# На странице поиска не переведены слова в подсказке по поиску

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, список-вопросов-участника

https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=test

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если развернуть "Советы по использованию расширенного поиска" на странице со списком вопросов участника, то там там многие слова не переведены.

- Exact: https://ru.traducir.win/string/11324
- Views: https://ru.traducir.win/string/11371
- Sections: https://ru.traducir.win/string/11345
- Favorites: https://ru.traducir.win/string/11364
- Status: https://ru.traducir.win/string/9156
- Types: https://ru.traducir.win/string/11373
- Exclude: https://ru.traducir.win/string/11344

Comment: Там ещё косяк с полем ["Answers"](https://ru.traducir.win/string/11357). Зачем-то множественные формы добавлены, которые тут неуместны. Я удивился, когда перевод добавлял, но думал, может это откуда-то из другого места.